# submitting form with Jquery submithandler

Tags: php, ajax

I can get Ajax to send the request successfully but I want it to also redirect to the new page and it's not redirecting. Could anyone suggest an alternative method or correct way to redirect?

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("div.error").hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo base_url().'subscribe/process_payment/'?>',
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );

        },          

        error: function(msg){
            console.log( "Error: " + msg);
        } 
    });
    return true;
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can simply do the redirect in the success function

```
success: function(msg){
        console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        window.location = "mysite.com/newURL";
},
```

or return the url

```
success: function(url){
        window.location = url;
},
```